# Why Form.Shown its happening before controls inside get load VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, load

Sorry for my bad english.

Im trying to do something after the main form get show, its a porgress bar, the problem its this getting fulled before an image get paint what its inside the form. I want to watch the image and label inside, and then start the loop.

I want something like Window.onload function of javascript

```
Private Sub FRM_CargaInicial_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        LBL_Carga.Visible = True
        Dim Dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        If conexion.EjecutarSQL("EXEC [GIM_RECURSOS].[IMAGEN].[SP_IMPORTAR]", Dt) Then
            PRB_Carga.Maximum = Dt.Rows.Count
            PRB_Carga.Value = 0
            For Each fila As DataRow In Dt.Rows
                Iconos.Add(New OBJIcono(fila.Item("ID_INFORMACION"), fila.Item("CLAVE"),     fila.Item("VALOR")))
                PRB_Carga.Value += 1
            Next fila
        End If
        Me.Hide()
        FRM_Ingreso.Show()
    End Sub
```

I tried PictureBox.LoadComplete and others events, all of them are throw before form load its completed.

Comment: Are you trying to create a splash screen that shows the loading progress of the main form?

Comment: That `Shown` event handler is executed on the UI thread. Each thread can only do one thing at a time so, while that method is being executed, the UI cannot be updated. You will simply see the final state once the method completes. There are various ways around that - some hacks, some good practice - but VB has splash screen functionality built in and that already uses an extra thread, so if that's what you're trying to do, that's what you should use.

Comment: hi ty for your answer. The same thing, do the load before Splash Screen show up, and using Shown event, the image never load just hide the splash screen and show the main form. @jmcilhinney

Comment: If you use the in-built splash screen functionality then there would be no reason to use the `Shown` event, so you're obviously doing it wrong. If you provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it, then we could probably provide a proper solution.